# stripe payment subscription not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I am using stripe in one of my codeigniter project.

I am using subscription method to add user to subscription.

This is my code of subscription.

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  "card" => $token,
  "plan" => "monthly",
  "email" => "user@domain.com",
  "description" => "user@domain.com",
));
```

Using this code I am creating new customer and adding to subscription plan.
This code create new user and add that user to subscription plan, but that user is not charge the amount.

Am I doing anything wrong or missing something?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_subscription shows how to create a subscription. If it's not working I'd recommend sharing more of your code & any errors you're getting here, or contacting support at https://support.stripe.com/email/login with details like the customer and subscription tokens, so they can look into the details.

Answer (score 0):

You may be best off creating the customer, card object, and subscribing the customer in separate actions. Stripe should automatically charge a customer when added to a subscription, but may be attempting to in the wrong order while doing it all at once? Have you tried separating them out? I've written the library below for use with CI and Stripe:

#### /application/libaries/Stripe.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Stripe {

    const PROCESS_URL = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1';
    const API_KEY = '{YOUR-STRIPE-API-KEY}'; 

    public $CI;
    public $db;

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CONSTRUCT
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =   &get_instance();
        $this->db =   $this->CI->db;
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CREATE CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function create_customer($request) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers';     
        return $this->post_request($process_url, $request); 
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_customer($cus_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id;     
        $customer_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 
        $customer_arr = json_decode($customer_obj);

        return $customer_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CUSTOMER
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_default_source($cus_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id;     
        $customer_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 
        $customer_arr = json_decode($customer_obj);
        $card_id = $customer_arr->default_source;

        return $card_id;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | GET CARD
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function get_card($cus_id,$card_id) {
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/cards/'.$card_id;     
        $card_obj = $this->post_request($process_url); 

        return $this->decode_response($card_obj);

    }

    /*
    |-----------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | ADD CARD
    | Params: Stripe Customer ID, Card Data Object
    |-----------------------------------------------
    */
    public function add_card($cus_id,$card_data) {
        $request = array(
            'source' => $card_data
        );
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/sources';     
        $card_json = $this->post_request($process_url,$request); 
        $card_obj = json_decode($card_json);

        // successful?
        if(isset($card_obj->id)) {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => true,
                'response' => $card_obj
            );
        } else {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $card_obj->error->message
            );   
        }

        return $ret_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | ADD CARD
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function subscribe_customer($cus_id,$plan_id,$source) {
        $request['plan'] = $plan_id;
        if($source) { $request['source'] = $source; }
        $process_url = self::PROCESS_URL.'/customers/'.$cus_id.'/subscriptions';     
        $plan_json = $this->post_request($process_url,$request); 
        $plan_obj = json_decode($plan_json);

        // successful?
        if(isset($plan_obj->id)) {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => true,
                'response' => $plan_obj
            );
        } else {
            $ret_arr = array(
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $plan_obj->error->message
            );   
        }

        return $ret_arr;

    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | DECODE JSON RESPONSE
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function decode_response($response) {
        return json_decode($response);
    }


    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | POST REQUESTS
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    public function post_request($url, $data = NULL)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            $data = http_build_query($data);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        return $this->do_curl_request($ch);
    }

    /*
    |-------------------------------------------
    | STRIPE | CURL REQUEST
    |-------------------------------------------
    */
    private function do_curl_request($ch)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, self::API_KEY);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_error($ch);

        if($response) {

        } else {
            var_dump($error);    
        }

        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Creating a customer, adding a card, and subscribing the customer to a given plan.

#### /application/controllers/myController.php

Load the Library

```
$this->load->library('stripe');
```

Create my Customer

```
// Create Stripe Customer
$request = array(
  "description" => {CUSTOMER-NAME},
  "metadata" => array(
    'First Name' => {CONTACT-FIRST-NAME},
    'Last Name' => {CONTACT-LAST-NAME},
    'Company Name' => {COMPANY-NAME}
  ),
  "shipping" => array(
    "name" => {CUSTOMER-NAME},
    "address" => array (
        "city" => {CITY},
        "state" => {STATE},
        "postal_code" => {ZIP},
        "line1" => {STREET-1},
        "line2" => {STREET-2},
    )
  ),
  "email" => $this->input->post('vendor_contact_email')
);

// Create the Customer
$stipe_response = $this->stripe->create_customer($request);
$response_arr = $this->stripe->decode_response($stipe_response);
$stripe_customer_id = $response_arr->id;
```

Add A Card

```
$data = array(
    "object" => 'card',
    "number" => {CARD-NUMBER},

    "address_city" => {BILLING-CITY},
    "address_state" => {BILLING-STATE},
    "address_zip" => {BILLING-ZIP},
    "address_line1" => {BILLING-ADDRESS},
    "address_line2" => {BILLING-ADDRESS-2},

    "name" => {BILLING-NAME},
    "exp_month" => {EXPIRATION-MONTH},
    "exp_year" => {EXPIRATION-YEAR},
);

// Add the Card
$stripe_response = $this->stripe->add_card($stripe_customer_id,$data);
$response_arr = $this->stripe->decode_response($stipe_response);
```

Subscribe the Customer

```
$stripe_response = $this->stripe->subscribe_customer($stripe_customer_id,{PLAN-ID},{SOURCE-ID});
$response_arr = $this->stripe->decode_response($stipe_response);
```

You can use the $response_arr to debug any responses you get from Stripe if you're having trouble. Hopefully this helps. I find the libarary is a bit easier to use than the Stripe SDK stuff.